# Setup Laravel as API location block on Nginx gives a 404

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to setup a website with React as my front-end and Laravel as my back-end. My server is an AWS instance setup with using Nginx on Ubuntu.

Currently I have Laravel in `/var/www/laravel` and my React code in `/var/www/html`. When I access the site `http://www.website.com` I can see my react placeholder, but when I try to access Laravel `http://www.website.com./api` I get a 404.

I have set all the permissions in Laravel correctly and all the all the php loads like it should. I can get Laravel working if I set everything in my default file to have Laravel be root.

Here's what my `default` file looks like:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    location /api {
            root /var/www/laravel/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
    }

    location @laravel {
            rewrite /api/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    location / {
            root /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to learn Nginx and Laravel so the above is somethings I pieced together after some Googlefoo.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you should fix these lines:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME **$request_filename**;  
rewrite /api/(.*)$ **/api**/index.php?/$1 last;
```

Faced a similar problem and found answers here:
https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory